# Get percent of page loaded. Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I get percents of page loaded with Vue.js in real time for to display it on this page? There is nothing in Google, everybody talks about setTimeout for this problem:) By the way, is it real?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an article [here](https://codepen.io/ahsanrathore/post/accurate-page-progress-bar) on using the Navigation Timing API to measure page load progress. Taking that as the base, you can create a `mixin` which can be used on your pages:

```
const PageLoadProgress = {
  created() {
      let perfData = window.performance.timing;
      let estimatedTime = Math.abs(perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart);
      this.loadTime = parseInt((estimatedTime / 1000) % 60) * 100;
      this.doProgress();
    },
    methods: {
      doProgress() {
        let step = this.loadTime / 100;
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
          this.loadingPercent++
        }, step);
      }
    },
    computed: {
      loaded() {
        return this.loadingPercent + '%'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      loadingPercent(val) {
        if (val >= 100) {
          console.log('complete');
          clearInterval(this.interval)
        }
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        loadingPercent: 0,
        loadTime: 0,
        interval: null
      }
    }
}
```

All this does is take the estimated page load time which then uses `setInterval` to calculate how often the percentage should be updated, I've also added a `watcher` to clear the interval when the load progress reaches 100%.

All you then need to do is display your load progress. I'm using a computed because it makes it easier to pass to the width attribute if you want to update a progress bar, so:

```
  <div v-if="loadingPercent < 100">
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <div class="fill" :style="{width:loaded}"> {{loaded}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    Page Loaded
  </div>
```

That's pretty much it. It's important to note that this is an estimate so the page may still not be completely loaded after the loader has reached 100%. If that's an issue you may want to attach an `onload` event to check that the load is complete, but I'll leave that up to you.

Anyway here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/13kmujoL/

Answer (score 1):

i was trying to do this last week.
I found that i couldn t get any percentage, only the moment of start, and end.

the only thing i could think of was this kind of simulation:

On the component that exits:

1. on beforeDestroy activate the loader and load it for like 30% in ~0.3s

On the component that enters

1. if you don t have any data that needs to load -> get loader to 100% in less time than the first 30%
2. if you have data that needs to load -> load another 30% in the same time as the first 30% -> trigger $http and when you get your response get loader to 100% in less time than the first 30%

My advice is to do this in a mixin with beforeDestroy to load 30% and a mounted event to load the next 70% based on a boolean variable "isDataToLoad" (default true) that you could transform to "false" (and load the 70% atumatically) in the created event that comes before mounted()

Hope it helps